# Display all documents list items, including subfolders in webpart using JSLink, as a tree view

Tags: web-part, folder, jslink

I'm trying to find a way to do this:
In a webpart on a page, create a tree view of all items in the "Documents" library, with folders, subfolders, and items (links to items).

So my idea was to add a Documents webpart on the page, and, using JSLink, output a html ul/li  list that can be easily tranformed into a tree view using 3rd party JS library. (e.g. jsTree)

Example: For a Documents library created as this :

- Folder 1

  - Folder 1.1

    - item A (itemA.ext)
    - item B (itemB.ext)
  - Folder 1.2

    - item C (itemC.ext)
    - item D (itemD.ext)
- Folder 2

  - ...

The ul/li would look like this

```
<ul>
    <li class="folder">Folder 1
        <ul>
            <li class="folder">Folder 1.1
                <ul>
                    <li class="item"><a href="xxx/itemA.ext">item A</li>
                    <li class="item"><a href="xxx/itemB.ext">item B</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="folder">Folder 1.2
                <ul>
                    <li class="item"><a href="xxx/itemC.ext">item D</li>
                    <li class="item"><a href="xxx/itemC.ext">item D</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="folder">Folder 2
        ....
    </li>
</ul>
```

And the tree result would be like:

[image: jsTree]

(of course, more than 2 levels might be used)
So i've added my Documents webpart, and added this JSLink:

```
var DocView = DocView || {};

DocView.itemHtml = function (ctx) {
    var title = ctx.CurrentItem.Title; 
    var fileRef = ctx.CurrentItem.FileRef;
    var fileLeafRef = ctx.CurrentItem.FileLeafRef;
    if (title) {
        return "<li><a href='"+ fileRef + "'>"+ title + "</a></li>"; 
    }
    else {
        return "<li>"+ fileLeafRef + "</li>"; 
    }
};

(function () {
    var DocuCtx = {};
    DocuCtx.Templates = {};
    DocuCtx.Templates.Header = "<ul class='allDocs'>";
    DocuCtx.Templates.Item = DocView.itemHtml;
    DocuCtx.Templates.Footer = "</ul>";

    DocuCtx.ListTemplateType = 101;
    //DocuCtx.BaseViewID = 99;

    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(DocuCtx);
})();
```

This results as a list of items located at first level of my Documents library.
I then tried to modify the default view of the library to display all files flat, without folders.
There, it displays all items flat, without folders.
and I don't have ctx.currentItem.Path value to add a manual logic to recreate the library hierarchy.

So questions:
Is this way of doing a good approach? (I mean with JSLink)
Any way to get the actual hierarchy structure of the library?
Any performance issues to expect if that library is quite huge? (~3-4 levels + a total of 300+ items inside)

Note: As simple owner of the site collections, I can't do much, other that use JS API, no server-side scripting possible...

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution.

Here it is:

I modified the view of my documents Library to display all elements flat, without folders.
Then I created this JSLink:

```
var DocuView = DocuView || {};

DocuView.itemHtml = function (ctx) {
    var title = ctx.CurrentItem.Title; 
    var fileRef = ctx.CurrentItem.FileRef;
    var fileLeafRef = ctx.CurrentItem.FileLeafRef;
    //if title defined, display it, otherwise display fileLeafRef, without aspx extension in case of link to document
    var displayTitle=(title)?title:(/\.aspx$/.test(fileLeafRef)?fileLeafRef.replace('.aspx',''):fileLeafRef);
    //split path to array to get different levels of hierarchy
    var path=fileRef.slice(fileRef.indexOf('Documents/')+10,fileRef.lastIndexOf('/')).split('/');
    //create a container outside the default container, because the JSLink will overwrite all content inside the default <td>
    //and load js+css files by adding to DOM
    if($('#docsTree').length==0) $('#script'+ctx.wpq).closest('tr').after('<tr><td><link rel="stylesheet" href="/sites/testSite/Tree/SiteAssets/style.min.css"/><script src="/sites/testSite/Tree/SiteAssets/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script><script src="/sites/testSite/Tree/SiteAssets/jstree.min.js"></script><script src="/sites/testSite/Tree/SiteAssets/jstree.search.js"></script><script src="/sites/testSite/Tree/SiteAssets/jstree.wholerow.js"></script><div id="docsTree"></div></td></tr>');
    if($('#docsTree>ul').length==0) $(dom).append('<ul>');
    //Clear path for root elements
    if(path.length==1 && path[0]=="") path=[];
    var dom='#docsTree';
    var domTarg;
    //for each level (folder), add it to the html list
    $(path).each(function(j,p){
        var domAdd=' li[data-path="'+p+'"]'
        dom+=domAdd;
        if($(dom).length==0){
            if($(dom.replace(domAdd,'')+'>ul').length==0) $(dom.replace(domAdd,'')).append('<ul>');
            $(dom.replace(domAdd,'')+'>ul').append('<li class="folder" data-jstree=\'{"icon":"'+ctx.imagesPath+'folder.gif"}\' data-path="'+p+'">'+p+'<ul><ul></li>')
        }
    });
    $(dom+'>ul').append('<li class="leaf" data-jstree=\'{"icon":"'+ctx.imagesPath+ctx.CurrentItem["HTML_x0020_File_x0020_Type.File_x0020_Type.mapico"]+'"}\'><a href="'+fileRef+'">'+displayTitle+'</a></li>')
    return ""
};

(function () {
    var DocuCtx = {};
    DocuCtx.Templates = {};
    DocuCtx.Templates.Header = '<div class="treeSearch"><input type="text" id="searchInput"/><a id="clearResults">Clear</a><div id="SearchMessage"></div></div>';
    DocuCtx.Templates.Item = DocuView.itemHtml;
    DocuCtx.Templates.Footer = '<script type="text/javascript">$(\'#docsTree\').jstree();</script>';

    DocuCtx.ListTemplateType = 101;
    //DocuCtx.BaseViewID = 99;

    DocuCtx.OnPostRender = postRenderHandler;   

    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(DocuCtx);
})();
function postRenderHandler(ctx) {
    $('#docsTree').jstree({
        plugins:["wholerow","search"]
    })
}
```

Remains the question of performance, I have to test with a huge library...

Comment: I'm trying to test this but couldn't get the Treeview to display. I tried loading jstree.js in a script src cewp above the documents web part but nothing is rendered.